# Next.js / Middleware project not fetching data properly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware, recoiljs

I'm following this tutorial by Sonny Sangha, and at 2:17:23 he manages to pull his playlist data from spotify.

Myself and many others in the comments of this video have been stumped trying to debug this issue. I'm almost certain the code is identical and all api requests return code 200, yet the playlist array remains empty.

[Problem code repo]https://github.com/Spix737/Spotify-Clone

[Youtube tutorial]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xrko3GpYoU

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: Some provided problematic code snippets would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't provide a snippet as there isn't any code breaking, I'm just not getting the intended functionality and I can't pinpoint why. Will do in future where applicable.